# How can I have alternating week numbers using a set date as week 1 in VB.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, daypilot

I am using daypilot pro to generate a timeline. As per usual, we had the project built and finalised to spec when a spanner was thrown in the works. The department this tool was built for works off "week 1" and "week 2".

Here is a screen shot as to where we are.
[image]

You will see "week 6" in the screen shot, this is generated from the following vb.net code.

```
Protected Sub DayPilotScheduler1_BeforeTimeHeaderRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DayPilot.Web.Ui.Events.BeforeTimeHeaderRenderEventArgs)

        If e.Level = 1 Then
            e.InnerHTML = String.Format("Week {0}", Week.WeekNrISO8601(e.Start))
        End If

    End Sub
```

What i want to do is generate alternating weeks, i.e. Week 1, Week 2, Week 1, Week 2. I will have to use a date identified by the department who want to use this tool as week 1, and calculate this going forward in the code.

Any advice or suggestions would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Does `Week.WeekNrISO8601(e.Start) Mod 2 + 1` give the required numbering?

Comment: Hi @AndrewMorton,  this has gotten me very close to what I need. It does indeed show week 1, week 2, week 1 etc. However i need to hardcode a set start date as week 1. would you have any suggestions?

Comment: How about `(Week.WeekNrISO8601(e.Start) + offsetWeekNumber) Mod 2 + 1`? You might have to add another 1 inside the brackets.

Comment: thanks @AndrewMorton, i have added ((Week.WeekNrISO8601(e.Start) + 2 + 1) Mod 2 + 1))` Removing the +1 or leaving it in allows me to set it to week one or week 2 from today, i tested the code by pushing the start date out by a week and looked into next year and the weeks seem to be lining up. When the actual clock ticks over into 2021 is this code robust enough that it will continue with week 1 and week 2 and not fall over and have week 1 then week 1 again? apologies for the question. Just want this off my desk and this seems to be a solution to it.

Comment: Those ISO weeks are funny things. I would write a quick little program to test it if I were you, perhaps check up until the year you expect to retire.

Comment: @AndrewMorton currently printing and framing that response!!! excellent!!!!!!!!!!!! Thanks for all your help!